# How do I set a value if a method is called from a child form?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

My application currently has 2 forms. It creates a sub form, Form2, which ends with the following code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{ ...
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.rglu = glu;
        frm.rdate = fulldate;
        frm.sort();
    Close();
}
```

Note that form1 is just a couple of buttons at the moment. One starts off Form2 as follows:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Form2 AcqForm = new Form2())
        {
            AcqForm.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
```

No other code runs except a button `test();` shown later).
This `frm.sort();` runs the following code found in Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void sort() 
    {           
        datelist = new List<DateTime>(rdate);
        datelist.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));

        var result = rdate
        .Select((d, i) => new { Date = d, Int = rglu[i] }) 
        .OrderBy(o => o.Date) 
        .ToArray();

        this.rdate = result.Select(o => o.Date).ToArray();
        this.rglu = result.Select(o => o.Int).ToArray();  //all works fine

        for (int i = 7; i+7 <= rglu.Length; i++)
        {
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(rdate[i]) + Convert.ToString(rglu[i]));
        } //This shows values as expected
    }
}
```

However when I set a button to run some more code using `rglu` and `rdate` the I get null pointer errors:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    private void test(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 7; i < rglu.Length; i++){} //rglu is null! The values are lost.
    }
}
```

I believe the solution requires a `int[] rglu {get; set;}` method. However so far I have been unsuccessful in using these things at all. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Edit:
rglu is defined like this:

```
public int[] rglu { get; set; } //I don't get how this works though
```

Comment: Is `Sort()` being executed before you call `test()`?

Comment: Yes it is being called beforehand.

Comment: When you call `Close()` in your initial snippet I suppose you've just closed Form2? 
Did you launch Form1 in some code that you haven't provided? Is the `test()` method on Form1 or Form2?

Comment: Yes form 2 closes after the sort has run I believe. Test is on Form 1.

Comment: Please can you post the portion of `class Form1` where `rglu` is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in form2,
You mustn't write 'Form1 frm = new Form1();' this code.

in Form1 wite code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int rglu;
        public DateTime rdate;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm2=new Form2();
            frm2.Form1Instance = this;
            frm2.Show();
        }
        public void sort()
        {
            datelist = new List<DateTime>(rdate);
            datelist.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));

            var result = rdate
            .Select((d, i) => new { Date = d, Int = rglu[i] })
            .OrderBy(o => o.Date) // Sort by whatever field you want
            .ToArray();

            this.rdate = result.Select(o => o.Date).ToArray();
            this.rglu = result.Select(o => o.Int).ToArray();  //all works fine

            for (int i = 7; i + 7 <= rglu.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(rdate[i]) + Convert.ToString(rglu[i]));
            } //This returns values as expected
        }
    }
}
```

in Form2 write codes like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form1 Form1Instance;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSortValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1Instance.rglu = glu;
            Form1Instance.rdate = fulldate;
            Form1Instance.sort();
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Purely from a defensive coding style point of view I think it would be good practice to test for `rglu` being null before calling methods on it.

e.g.

```
public void test() 
{
    if(rglu == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("rglu is null!");
    } 

    for (int i = 7; i < rglu.Length; i++){} //rglu is not null!
}
```

I'd also question why test() needs to be public if it's called from a button click event.

Comment: There is way more code than I have shown, forgive me, I'm simplifying for the question. test() doesn't need to be public.

Answer (score 0):

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.rglu = glu;
frm.rdate = fulldate;
frm.sort();
Close();
```

You don't use `frm` variable anywhere else and don't display the form, so garbage collectior is the only one who is going to receive that data in `rdate` and `rglu` variables in this case.

It seems like you wanted to operate on already existing form. In this case you must pass a reference to existing `Form1` to your method in `Form2`.

**Update:**

It may look like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    // ...
    private readonly Form1 _parent;

    public Form2(Form1 parent) : this()
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }

    // ... somewhere in a method which closes Form2:

        Form1 frm = _parent;
        frm.rglu = glu;
        frm.rdate = fulldate;
        frm.sort();
        Close();

    // ...
}
```

To show `Form2` from `Form1`, use

```
using(var form2 = new Form2(this))
{
    form2.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Comment: adding a parameter of type `Form1` to `Form2` constructor will be the easiest way

Comment: That was my thought too, but this may be a very simplified code snippet. If Form1 has not been shown then there's no way to click the `Test()` button, so I think we're missing some information.

Comment: Form 1 is just 2 buttons on a blank form, one opens form 2, one runs test().